# Re-Installing MYSQL database on a webserver without losing the settings

Tags: apache2, mysql

Can you re-install MYSQL on an ubuntu server, without deleting the created databases, privileges and other settings? Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, @vidarlo, for the book suggestion. You are right; this is a broad topic. Do you think I should delete the question or just leave it there? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks again for your patience with this. As I said, programming databases are new to me, but I find it interesting. I will move on with reading the books you suggested. I will also flag this question  for removal in the interest of the ubuntu community.

Comment: Will you provide a mysqldump of the structure (no data) of the mysql database?  I'll use that to create a working web interface template to communicate with it.

Comment: So I guess I should have put my question like this: How do you communicate with a database using a web interface?

Answer (score 2):

Pl. clarify what do you mean by 'posting a database on website' !
I suggest you need to get some insight about three tiers of such project.
1) Database tier,
2) Business logic tier,
3) UI tier.

Since you say that you have setup MySQL, Apache web server and phpMyAdmin, you seem to know how to do it.
In a commercial business app, typically hosting is done on own server(s) of an organisation (with advanced approaches such as mirroring, load balancing, optimizing, etc.)
If it is a small organisation, hosting is done on leased server space / cloud hosting.

It would help us understand your question better (and answer it in a better way) if you can give more details.
HTH

Comment: Thanks for your interest in this question. I edited the question to reflect answers to your question.

Comment: Looking at your Edit, I suggest you try MVC architechture from a wide variety available in open source web frameworks. My personal choice would be web2py framework (it is in python) or any other suitable one. There are frameworks available in php also. Just search for it. Such framework would probably satisfy all of your needs in this regard. For newbies also, it is quite simple to create a CRM project.  You can choose database of your choice without worrying for the syntax of DDL or DML. The framework will write it for you. Even you can switch the database midway, if you wish.

Comment: Thanks! I looked up web2py and like their approach and philosophy very much, however, I have not yet been able to install it on ubuntu. Any suggestions on the best approach to installing it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Under ubuntu, you need not install it. Just Download the source and run web2py.py from python shell. http://web2py.com/init/default/download gives help in this regard.